# replaceWith(); JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, replacewith

I'm trying to include what should be a simple JQuery snippet into a friend's portfolio website to replace:

```
<div class="content one">
<h3>Content Title</h3>
<p>Body text.</p>
</div>
```

With:

```
<div class="content two">
<h3>Content Title</h3>
<p>Body text.</p>
</div>
```

When hovering on a separate div class of:

```
<div class="item two"><!--content two icon-->
<img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

I have these separate classes of `<div class="item">` that have icons in them. I want to be able to hover over the icon's class and replace the `<div class="content">` class with another one that corresponds to the `<div class="item">` icon.

For the JQ, I'm using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.item two').hover(function(){
$('.content one').replaceWith($('.content two'));
});
</script>
```

I have each content class (except .content one) as `display: none;` I think I need to throw in a `.show();` event inside of the `replaceWith();` function, but even if I remove `display: none;` on the classes, nothing replaces itself with the class I'm trying to replace.

I'm still relatively new to JQuery and JavaScript as a whole, so it's probably something stupid simple that I'm not doing right. Forgive me if I didn't include enough information to help you figure out the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Woot! You guys rock! That fixed it up straight away. I knew it was something stupid simple I was missing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.item.two').hover(function(){
    $('.content.one').replaceWith($('.content.two'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two classes on the same element in both cases, so your selectors should be:

```
.item.one
.item.two
.content.two
.content.two
```